# Create a new column or field with PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

How do I create a new column or field (idnew) in an existing Access database (resultdb) using PHP PDO?.

Comment: Run a `ALTER..ADD` query, `ALTER TABLE resultdb ADD idnew int` - although using tools like phpMyAdmin makes this a lot easier.

Comment: Wouldn't you create the column (or change the schema in any way) with a database management tool, rather than from code?

Answer (score -2):

You are able to create new columns with the query function as well as the prepared statement function. Whitch one you should use depends on what you want to do with it.

**Example 1**

```
$pdo->query('ALTER TABLE resultdb ADD idnew INT(11)');
```

**Example 2**

```
function addColumn($column, $type)
{
  $query = $pdo->prepare('ALTER TABLE resultdb ADD :column :type');
  $query->execute(array(':column' => $column, ':type' => $type));
}
addColumn('idnew', 'INT(11)');
```

Be careful that you are not destroying any functions built in you website by doing this.

Comment: No, you cannot parse data into `execute()` for `ALTER`.